# Split Multi-Extension fits file - fits.fz format

Tags: photometry, fits, fits-header, ds9

I have **CFHT/MegaCam fits.fz** file on which I want to do photometry. I want to **split these large fits.fz file into separate CCD detector fits** and then run Source Extractor on them for photometric analysis. I am not familiar with this extension. I opened this in DS9, it shows 2 headers. How do I split this file? Below is the DS9 image of it. [image]

Comment: You're conflating two things. The ".fz" extension means the file has been compressed (https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/fpack/); this has nothing to do with whether or not it is multi-extension. (SAOimage DS9 automatically decompresses the file when it opens it.)

Comment: Splitting the file into separate, single-extension image files can probably best be done (these days) with the `fits` library in `astropy.io`; see, e.g., [here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html).

Comment: @PeterErwin but DS9 only displays one of them (automatically). I have extracted all the 40 fits files inside it. Can I display the mosaic of all 40 images at once, either in python or ds9?

Comment: You can get DS9 to open and display all the image extensions via File -> Open as -> Multiple Extension Frames ... [this will open each image in its own frame].

You can also try File -> Open as -> Mosaic WCS ...